# Programmatically Determining Bin Path

Tags: python

I'm working on a web app called `pj` and there is a `bin` file and a `src` folder.

The relative paths before I deploy the app will look something like:

`pj/bin` and `pj/src/pj/script.py`.

However, after deployment, the relative paths will look like:

`pj_dep/deployed/bin` and `pj_dep/deployed/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pj/script.py`

Question:

Within `script.py`, I am trying to find the path of a file in the `bin` directory. This leads to 2 different behaviors in the dev and deployment environment.

If I do

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'bin')
```

to try to get the path for the dev environment, I will have a different path for the deployment environment.

Is there a more generalized way I can find the bin directory so that I do not need to rely on an `if` statement to determine how many directories to go up based on the current env? This doesn't seem flexible and might cause other issues later on when the code is moved.

EDIT: My guess is that I might be able to do this with the `setup.py`, but I am not familiar enough with the file to determine where to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, these directories are not dynamically **found**, but previously **configured**.

If your application is simply an utility, you can have two configuration files (perhaps `json`, `yaml`, or even `py` files). Use one of these files during development, and bundle the other file with the final build. They would look like this:

```
# config.json
{
    'path_script': 'foo/pj/lib/script.py'
    'path_bin': 'foo/pj/bin'
}
```

Your program always looks for `config.json` in the same place: you switch files when you build app for distribution.

If your application is a server, the cleanest approach is to use environment variables in a sourceable shell file. This works well with virtualenv. For example, you could have this `env` file in your project root:

```
source virtualenv/bin/activate

# In the production environment, before sourcing this script, declare `APP_ENV`

if [[ $APP_ENV = "PRODUCTION" ]]; then
    export PATH_SCRIPT="foo/pj/lib/script.py"
    export PATH_BIN="foo/pj/bin"

else
    export PATH_SCRIPT="foo/bar/pj/lib/script.py"
    export PATH_BIN="bar/baz/pj/bin"
fi
```

When you open a shell to develop, `source env` instead of your `virtualenv`. When running the app in production, `export APP_ENV="PRODUCTION"` before sourcing. You can set environment variables in `upstart`, `supervisor` or `systemd`, whatever software you're using to run your server.

Note that this approach extends to any other configuration you might need, since most of it varies between development and production: SQL addresses and logins, API keys, etc.